# WebView loading images from phone gallery

Tags: android, image, webview

I'm trying to have the user pick an image from the phone's gallery. Then using the webview to display the image. The file path retrieved is something like "content://media/external/images/media/14". when i looked at other problems, seems like their file path usually start with "file://"

When the program is ran, it displays a long list of random characters. Not sure whats wrong, help is appreciated. thank you

edit this has been solved thx to Md Abdul Gafur's link.
new fixed code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //message is the path of the file.

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_large);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    String html = "<html><head></head><body><p>hello</p><img src=\"" + message + "\" alt=\"alternativo\" /></body></html>";
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

}
```

Comment: please check the [link][1]. It help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276241/showing-image-from-sdcard-with-webview-not-working

Thanks

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/image-display-and-interaction-with-android-webviews/

Comment: thank you, the first linked help.